# Constraints Issue with alert popover

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

quick one here. I have tried setting a breakpoint and I can't seem to see where the issue is coming from. So here's the code:

It's a popover alert button that presents a constraint issue when clicked.

```
private lazy var SocialBtn: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.setTitle(" + ", for: .normal)
        
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30)
        button.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
```

here is how I set up the button:

```
 @objc private func btnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        alert.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        
        let image = UIImage(named: "instagram")
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = image
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.frame =  CGRect(x: 25, y: 12, width: 35, height: 35)
        alert.view.addSubview(imageView)
        
        let image1 = UIImage(named: "tripadvisor")
        let imageView1 = UIImageView()
        imageView1.image = image1
        imageView1.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        alert.view.addSubview(imageView1)
        imageView1.frame = CGRect(x: 25, y: 60, width: 40, height: 50)
        
        let shareExternal = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Tripadvisor", comment: ""), style: .default) { action in
            
            if let url = URL(string: self.link1) {
                if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
                }
            }
        }
        let shareInApp = UIAlertAction(title: "Instagram", style: .default)   {
            action in
            
            print("Insta")
            
            if let url = URL(string: self.link2) {
                if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
                }
            }
        }
        
        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel)   {
            action in
            
            print("cancel")
        }
        
        alert.addAction(shareInApp)
        alert.addAction(shareExternal)
        alert.addAction(cancel)
        
        if let presenter = alert.popoverPresentationController
        {
            presenter.sourceView = SocialBtn
            presenter.sourceRect = SocialBtn.bounds
        }
        
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

When I click the button the issue given to me is:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x283694e60 UIView:0x116024990.width == - 16   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x283694e60 UIView:0x116024990.width == - 16   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: “Please point me in the right direction." Two things. First did you try the symbolic breakpoint as stated? Second, don't add subview to `UIAlertController`, behavior won't be guaranteed. From the doc: "The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified."

Comment: @Larme thank you for your response. Yes I did try the symbolic breakpoint but no joy. Is it possible that adding it as a subview is causing this?

Comment: As stated, it's not recommended to change its view hierarchy. You can do as you want, but tomorrow, it could break (well even if in your case, it might no be the case, but they could ignore them and remove the subview added, that's a possibility) and even make a crash.

Comment: @Larme can you recommend a better way to achieve the same sort of popover alert?

Comment: @Larme have you had a chance to look at this?

Comment: Create your own one, or look for a open source one (Github, CocoaPods, CocoaControls, etc.)